# neo4j: Custom script names

Tags: neo4j

Operational question about the GUI of neo4j: I have a couple of cypher queries I keep using over and over again. I've created script files for them and I have added them to the star-menu by drag+dropping them in "Drop cypher script file to import". I then see the first few lines of content in the menu.

Instead, I would rather define a custom label, which quickly tells me what the script does or when it's supposed to be used. Is there any way I can define the "bookmark name" so to speak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using a '//' style comment in the first line, e.g.

```
// that is the title of my query
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

Comment: That'll do. Not as fancy as the sample queries listed under "General", but good enough for my use. Thanks!